# Is 結構くせ related to 結構人?

Tags: definitions, synonyms

I recently came across the word 「結構くせ」. Haven't found any entries for it in the usual places (zokugo-dict, WWWJDIC, etc.) According to [kotobank](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%B5%90%E6%A7%8B%E4%BA%BA), 結構人 is a synonym for お人好し.

Is 結構くせ the (negative) habit of being an お人好し?

Context: （省略）…消費者には、結構くせがある。

Comment: You seem to be treating 「結構くせ」 as one word, are you not?  What was the context you found it in?  Words had to follow it if not precede it, right?  I have two possibilities in my mind already but I will wait for further context.

Comment: I am. I'll edit it with context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[結構]{けっこう} is an extremely often-used word meaning "fairly", "pretty (much)", "to a (great) degree", etc.

結構くせがある means "to have pretty strong or peculiar habits"

くせ ＝ [癖]{くせ} ＝ habit

Lastly, [結構人]{けっこうじん} has nothing to do with 結構くせがある.  It means a "very likable person".

Comment: I wonder why my mental parser failed on this one?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander Perhaps because adverbs (as in 副詞) are a pretty small class of words in Japanese, so if you tried to parse it purely probabilistic based on the characters, guessing it to be a noun-noun compound is a reasonable choice (ignoring any semantics of the words, which is a little silly :-).

Comment: True, and 結構 is pretty poorly behaved in terms of contemporary usage :P