# What does 結構 mean as a sentence starter?

Tags: word-usage

> 結構、自然の動画とかを 撮っているんですけど そんなに田舎じゃないです

Rough translation: "Even though I shoot nature videos (here), it's not really that much of a countryside."

I assume 結構 here means something like "often".  Is this an unusual way to use the word?

My dictionary gives these meanings:

1. good, fine, nice, all right
2. satisfactory, sufficient, agreeable
3. pretty well, quite, rather, tolerably, surprisingly

The meaning 3 is close but none of them really fit.

Comment: Where did you see this sentence?

Comment: Wouldn’t you be asking this if 結構 were placed right before 撮っている?

Comment: @Angelos https://youtu.be/rsIXTRNt-W4?t=13 but I've seen similar structures in other places.

Comment: @aguijonazo I would have the same question if it was right in front of 撮っている.　i do understand examples where it qualifies a verb but those are with verbs that describe a state or feeling: 結構いける, 結構役に立つ

Comment: Did you check the word class? I suppose only the meaning 3 is marked as an adverb. The other two are probably (na-)adjectival usages of 結構.

Comment: Related: [Why does 結構 precede the noun instead of the verb in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78266/43676), [What does 経つ mean with 結構?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76326/43676), [Is 結構くせ related to 結構人?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14085/43676), [meaning of 結構がち](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48491/43676), [translation: とか and 結構](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48229/43676), [Difference Between かなり～ and 結構～ as Adverbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64421/43676)

Comment: @naruto Unfortunately, my dictionary (研究社新英和大辞典) does not show type of speech (形容詞, 名詞, etc). Do you know any Japanese-English dictionary that does? At least the examples in (3) do show usage as an adverb (and as an adjective).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 結構 is not unnatural. The third definition seems closest, but when 結構 is used adverbially, it has a meaning of both "rather/unexpectedly" and "often/fairly/well". In other words, it implies the degree/frequency is higher than one might expect. In this case, how about "*rather* often" or "quite often" as a translation?

According to 明鏡国語辞典 第三版:

> #### 結構
>
> 三［副］予想した以上であるさま。極端ではないが、かなりの程度であるさま。
> 「今度の試験は**結構**いいところまで行くかもしれない」
> 「輪投げも**結構**難しいものだ」
> 「**結構**席が空いている」

Similar examples:

- 結構おいしかったですよ。
  It was rather delicious! / It tasted better than you think.
- え、結構簡単じゃない？
  Oh, isn't this rather easy?
  <sub>(But not "Isn't this very easy?")</sub>